# Property of Gridview class Cells dows not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why property of GridView Control "Cells" does not show.
Can anyone help me regarding this?

## Code :

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(GridView row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        int enrollment = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);
        String student1 = row.Cells[1].Text;
        RadioButton rbt1 = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("Present") as RadioButton);
        RadioButton rbt2 = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("Absent") as RadioButton);
        String status;
        if(rbt1.Checked)
        {
            status = "Present";
        }
        else
        {
            status = "Absent";
        }
        String date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        String division = txtDepartment.SelectedValue;
        String shift = txtShift.SelectedValue;
        String year = txtYear.SelectedValue;
        SaveAttendance(enrollment, student1, date, status, division, shift, year);
    }
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Attendance Saved SuccessFully !!')</script>");
}
```

## Compile Time Error :

[image: Watch this picture]

## Error :

[image: See the Error]

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: See i have added error

Comment: see my answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should utilize `GridViewRow` instead of `GridView` in `foreach` loop below

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
.....
```